# Save child relations with parent entity TypeORM

Tags: node.js, typescript, postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

I'm inserting multiple entries simultaneously and wanted to store the child relationships as well, but using the code below, `province` isn't saving into the database. In essence, I want to save the "province" and `user` when I save the `address`, and I receive the `userID` and `provinceID` in the request.

`entity.ts`

```
@Entity()
export class Address {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  id: string;

  @Column()
  address1: string;

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  address2?: string;

  @Column()
  country: string;

  @ManyToOne(() => Province, (province) => province.addresses, { lazy: true })
  @JoinColumn({
    name: 'province_id',
  })
  province: Province;

  @ManyToOne(() => User, (user) => user.addresses, {
    nullable: false,
    onDelete: 'CASCADE',
    lazy: true,
  })
  @JoinColumn({
    name: 'user_id',
  })
  user: User;
}
```

`Request from frontend`:

```json
[
    {
        "address1": "Test 1",
        "address2": "Test 1",
        "country": "Estonia",
        "province_id": "3", // suppose uuid
        "user_id": "4" // suppose uuid
    },
    {
        "address1": "Test 2",
        "address2": "Test 2",
        "country": "Estonia",
        "province_id": "3",  // suppose uuid
        "user_id": "4" // suppose uuid
    }
]
```

`service.ts`

```js
async saveAddresses (_addresses) {
      const addresses: any = _addresses.map((address) => ({
        ...address,
        user: address.user_id,
        province: address.province_id
      }));
      const addressesToCreate = this.addressRepository.create(addresses);
      await this.addressRepository.insert(addressesToCreate);
}
```

As you can see how I'm saving the records but unfortunately, the province and user saving as null and I don't want to query for province again n again.

Answer (score -1):

I tried like this [article](https://progressivecoder.com/typeorm-entity-relations/), and works for me

The code:

```
//Entity
@Entity('organization')
export class Organization {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  id: string;

  @Column({ type: 'varchar' })
  name: string;

  @OneToMany(() => Users, (obj) => obj.organization)
  users: Users[];
}

@Entity('users')
export class Users {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  id: string;

  @Column({ type: 'varchar' })
  name: string;

  @ManyToOne(() => Organization, (obj) => obj.users, { cascade: true }) // <--- cascade: true
  organization: Organization;
}
```

```
//Service
async create(dto: CreateDto[]) {
    try {
      const orgEntity = function (name: string) {
        const org = new Organization();
        org.name = name;
        return org;
      };

      const entity: any = dto.map((obj) => ({
        ...obj,
        organization: orgEntity(obj.organization),
      }));

      const entityCreated = this._repoUser.create(entity);
      await this._repoUser.save(entity); // <-- save

      return entityCreated;
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  }
```

```
//dto
export class CreateDto {
  @ApiProperty()
  @IsString()
  name: string;

  @ApiProperty()
  @IsString()
  organization: string;
}
```

```
//request
[
  {
    "name": "user-1", 
    "organization":"org-1"
  },
  {
    "name": "user-2", 
    "organization":"org-2"
  }
]
```

Comment: I've revised it, hope it helps